# How to change the port number 8081 of mongo-express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to change mongo-express port number from 8081 to 8082. Because 8081 is use by react-native. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

In Mongo-Express the port is defined in `config.default.js` as:

```
port: process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8081
```

If you copy `config.default.js` to `config.js` as they suggest in the the [README](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express) you can change the port to whatever you like. Alternatively, as you can see, you can also set the `VCAP_APP_PORT` environmental variable with something like:

```
export VCAP_APP_PORT=8082
```

Comment: If you are using Docker, there is a variable `VCAP_APP_PORT` which can be set within docker-compose under the `mongo-express` service